# Export excel to pdf layout changes

Tags: excel, vba

So i have searched for hours now and did not find a solution.
I am trying to export sheets that have a print area to PDF but the PDF layout is different than what i see when i check the print preview.

i am using excel 2010.

Does anyone know why this happens.

code i use to export

```
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        filename:=filename, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution. apparently its something with the settings.

> In Excel, go to File > Options > Advanced. Under General section,
>   uncheck ‘Scale content for A4 or 8.5 x 11” paper size’ and click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting the document, why dont you print the sheet and set the printer to PDF printer something like.

```
Sub PrintTest() ' This will print multiple sheets based on a certain criteria
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim i As Long: i = 0
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Mid(sh.Name, 1, 4) = "Test" Then ' Change the conditional statement
            sh.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
            ReDim Preserve arr(i)
            arr(i) = sh.Name
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next sh
    Dim printSheets As Variant
    printSheets = arr
    Worksheets(printSheets).PrintOut Preview:=False, ActivePrinter:="Adobe PDF", PrintToFile:=True, PrToFileName:=PSFileName
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but do i need to install something because the code is running but i cant see any output.

Comment: I see that i have to install that. But that is not an option for me.

Comment: if you have Adobe Acrobat already installed, you should have the pdf printer also

Comment: It's not for me so i wouldn't know, but thanks anyway.